# How to make numericInput() in R shiny App dynamic?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I'm trying to make a `numericInput()` function in R Shiny dynamic. I was able to make this input dynamic and work correctly using `selectInput()`, but I switched it to `numericInput()` and it no longer works. I'm confused with the value, max, and min settings in `numericInput()`. Basically, I'd like the default value for the "End month of study window" (`winEnd`) to always equal the maximum of the `mos` column - `input$winStart`, as illustrated immediately below and per the code at the bottom of this post. Any recommendations for how to do this?

[image]

Code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)

testDF <- data.frame(
  mos = as.integer(c(10,6,10,4,8,3)),
  status = as.integer(c(1,1,0,1,1,0))
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  numericInput("winStart","Start month of study window:",value = 0, max = 4, min = 0),
  numericInput("winEnd","End month of study window:", value = 40, max = 40, min = 5),
  h5("Columns `mos` and `status` are original testDF; extra columns added via reactive `tmp()`:"),
  tableOutput("table1")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  tmp <- reactive({testDF %>%
      mutate(mos1 = as.integer(pmax(1,mos-input$winStart))) %>%
      mutate(mos2 = pmin(mos1,input$winEnd)) %>%
      mutate(status1 = if_else(mos1 > mos2,as.integer(0),status))
  })
  
  observe({
    updateNumericInput(
      session, 
      "winEnd", 
      value = max(tmp()$mos2), # works fine except end of study window doesn't reflect reductions in start of study window
      # value = max(tmp()$mos - input$winStart), # this doesn't allow you to reduce window end
      max = max(tmp()$mos - input$winStart), 
      min = 5
      )
  })
  
  output$table1 <- renderTable({tmp()})
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are changing the `max` value of the `input$winEnd`, to match the max 'mos' but not the actual `value`.

And since it seems like you only want the `input$winEnd` to update when `input$winStart` is altered, why don't you wrap the `updateNumericInput` in an `observeEvent` instead of just an `observe`? Like this:

```r
observeEvent(input$winStart, {
  max_val <- max(tmp()$mos - input$winStart) 
  updateNumericInput(
    session, 
    "winEnd", 
    value = max_val,
    max = max_val, 
    min = 5
  )
})
```